# Semisimplicity of Frobenius action on H^1(X,Q_p)

Tags: etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over a finite field of characteristic $p$, with Hasse-Witt invariant $\lambda>1$.

For $\ell\neq p$, the Frobenius action on the etale cohomology group $H^1(X,\mathbb Q_\ell)$ is semisimple. Is the statement still true when $\ell=p$?

Does anyone have a good reference, or a counterexample? Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of $H^1(X,\mathbb{Q}_l)$ when $l=p$?